# Firefox keydown not working when page is initially loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

This maybe a no brainer to you. but I am trying to figure out why keydown is not triggered in firefox upon an initial load.

```
$(document).keydown(function(){alert("test")})
```

I add the above code in my javascript and when I open my page and without clicking anything but pressing key. I can see that the key pressed is not cautch at all. However, after I click the background of my page then I press keyboard. I can see the key is caught then.

This doesn't happen in Chrome, only in Firefox.

Is anyone familiar with this by any chance.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your page isn´t in focus? Can you make a fiddle of it not working?

Comment: @putvande Thanks for your reply, I think you are correct, but how can I make it to focus? using Jquery's focus()?